# ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebAPI Execution Flow diffrences

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

This question is related to my another question: [ASP MVC Message Handlers vs Web API Message Handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880306/asp-mvc-message-handlers-vs-web-api-message-handlers).

The pretty much exact ASP.NET MVC execution flow was described here: [Execution flow in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982517/execution-flow-in-mvc). Although, I can't find equivalent for ASP.NET WebAPI.

My question is:
What are specific differences between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebAPI execution flows? What is the diffrence "under the hood" if I send a GET request to a WebAPI Service and a GET request to MVC WebSite?

It would be nice to have them compared step by step.

Comment: One great post about MVC pipeline: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/an-introduction-to-asp.net-mvc-extensibility/